# The difference in between two different rows and also different columns in R

Tags: r

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzV55.png)[image]

This is for R.

I attached the question in a picture. If I need the delta from two different rows that at the same time are in two different columns . How do I code that in R?

result <- raw_data %>%
group_by(`Order`) %>%
arrange(Order,`On Time Start`)

result1 <- result %>%
group_by(Order) %>%
mutate(Queue = difftime(`On Time Start`, lag(`On Time Comp` , units = c("days"))))

Comment: Forgot to add.  This has to be grouped for each Serial number before doing the calculation .  Serial number is a different column. Thanks

Comment: Please don't attach pictures of data/code. Make it easier for people who are trying to help you. Add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: I added a new image , click image description here .    I am getting a big delta,  it should not be that much.

Comment: The values you are getting is in seconds, you can change the units to "mins", "hours", "days", "weeks" in `difftime`.

Comment: It is working now . Thanks!  I am new at R , this is great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by  `Serial_number` and calculate the difference between the two times.

```
result <- df %>% 
           group_by(Serial_number) %>%
           mutate(Queue = difftime(start_date_A, lag(start_date_B),units = "days"))
```

Comment: Something is still not working. Is there a way I can send the data frame I am using so you can see it

Comment: As per Ronak's comment, you can use dput on the data frame and edit your question to include the code